# Can't update the record because foreing keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, schema, updating

I can't UPDATE (not delete) a record because foreign keys from auxiliar tables doesn't let me do it.

I know I can disabled the foreign keys but I do not consider a well practice if just I'm updating "customer" table, which has not any FK to auxiliar ones.

Any solution to this issue?

My DB-Schema
  [image: DB Schema[1]]

One of the auxiliar table FK

[image: One of the FK]

The error what I'm getting

[image: The error what I'm getting]

And this is the code I'm using to do that

```
  $customer = Customer::where('id', $id)->update($data);
  if($customer)
      return redirect('/customers/);
```

Comment: Add the update query or the code you use when you get this error.

Comment: added the current code i'm using, wich is working if i disabled the foreign keys, which I don't want

Comment: You should use delete succesfully. But can't update, because cascade method. Change update, none to cascade. Probably work.

Comment: Are you trying to update the id of the customer? What do you have in `$data`?

Comment: That was it! I unset the id field from the array and it is working! Many thanks TheFallen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to #TheFallen to help me.

In the array I was including the ID of the own record, so I took it out from the array and the update order is working with active foreing keys.